# Limit Chrome Extension to certain URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to limit a Chrome extension to only run on certain urls?

Say I want the extension to run only if the domain is Amazon.com. I realize you can put a check at the top of the scripts, then execute the rest of the script only if the check matches.

However, can you prevent the extension from running at all?

Answer (score 27):

Welp, it figures I would find the answer to this right after posting the question, even though I have been stuck for a while...

Archive of version of docs originally linked in answer:
[http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120503223135/http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

> Analog page for Manifest V2 (though [see also V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/)):
> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/

In manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.nytimes.com/*"],
      "exclude_matches": ["*://*/*business*"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: FYI This doesn't prevent the script from running, it prevents chrome from injecting it into pages that don't match.

Comment: True, I guess that was the nature of my original question, should have worded it more carefully, Thanks.

Comment: Side note: The URL’s path part after the domain name, e.g. the `/watch/` part in `"matches": [ "https://www.netflix.com/watch/*" ],` is not ignored, even though it is confusingly omitted in the extension details view: `https://www.netflix.com/*`

Comment: Can the matches be dynamic like taking input from user?

Answer (score 9):

As a user, with Chrome 71 (or maybe even before) with chrome://flags/#extension-active-script-permission (you may need to enable **User consent for extension scripts** flag) allows you to right click extension icons and select "This can read and change site data" then you can choose:

- When you click the extension
- On current-domain-name.com
- On all sites (default)

[image]

This way you can limit an extension to only run on certain domains very quickly.

Comment: Limit as a _user_, or as a _developer?_

Comment: @Xan You're right the question isn't very clear either, so I added "as a user".

Comment: I believe that from the context: 1) It's a question on StackOverflow (and not, say, Super User), 2) The original author self-responded with "how to do it through an extension manifest", the intent here is a developer question. Which makes it important to at least note that **developers have no control over this mechanism.** Though it's not fully off-topic as developers need to be aware of this, and may need to inform the users of this.

Comment: This flag is available from Chrome version 37.0.1991.0

Comment: What about blacklist URLs? Black lists for all extension that never runs?

Comment: Does that change turn the plugin off? Or just block it? I want to turn it off, to reduce memory footprint, as some plugins are dedicated to a single website.

Answer (score -1):

There's a Chrome extension for this: [Extension Automation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-automation/ghopjgdkodchjclkkfdekhjfomdbakkb). I had gone the route of modifying manifests before, but this is easier.

Comment: It's 404 Not Found.