# how to limit chrome extensions to certain domains?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As an end user, I would like to restrict the extensions to run only on certain domains.  Like an extension that needs to enhance gmail, to only trigger on mail.google.com.

I am reposting this question from [Limit Chrome Extension to certain URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504239/limit-chrome-extension-to-certain-urls)

The OP wanted it for extension developer.  But as an end user, I wanted this for protecting myself from rouge extension or just to make the page load faster without triggering all the extensions.

I found that the original post had the answer for this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53315464/1500545

since the OP's need was for developers, I was not highly upvoted.  Will post the answer here and accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit Chrome Extension to certain URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504239/limit-chrome-extension-to-certain-urls)

Answer (score -4):

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/users/167897/wernight

As a user, with Chrome 71 (or maybe even before) with chrome://flags/#extension-active-script-permission (you may need to enable User consent for extension scripts flag) allows you to right click extension icons and select "This can read and change site data" then you can choose:

When you click the extension
On current-domain-name.com
On all sites (default)

[image]